# What does { [native code] } mean in WebKit's Inspector?

Tags: javascript, function, binary, interpreter

For instance, open up a JS console, and type `toString<Enter>`.

You'll get this:

```
function toString() { [native code] }
```

Contrast this with:

```
function foo() { return 'bar'; }
foo
```

which produces:

```
function foo() { return 'bar'; }
```

Does it mean that its an API to the interpreter which directly executes some internal routines in C or whatever is used to program it when that method is called?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787873/safari-native-code

Comment: It means the function is implemented by the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[native code]` is simply a label that indicates that the implementation details of the function body are handled "natively" by the browser.

Comment: So in practice that would typically mean either something akin to the "shadow DOM" or compiled binary code?